# Duvida sobre o funcionamento do socket.io

Tags: socket, websocket, socket.io

Tenho uma dúvida em respeito ao socket.io que já pesquisei em vários lugares e a maioria da uma enrolada ou usa uns termos obscuros, mas acaba não respondendo a dúvida diretamente.

A dúvida é se ele funciona da seguinte maneira: na hora do server de enviar uma mensagem para o usuário ele por acaso registra o "endereço" do usuário de alguma forma e depois manda a comunicação direto para este endereço sem o usuário precisar fazer nenhum request (ajax ou direto)? E meu server pode ter vários usuários "registrados" cada um recebendo mensagens apenas de um outro usuário específico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim.

O socket.io nada mais faz do que abstrair uma conexão de websocket para você.

A conexão do socket é entre o usuário e o servidor, portanto para realizar o que você será necessário realizar algum tipo de login, nem que seja apenas um nick (num exemplo de chat) para que você possa associar o nick com um socket.

Você irá ter um mapa de nicks/logins que apontam para seu socket.

Quando você quiser criar um canal entra o usuário A e B acontecerá o seguinte cenário:

A envia dados para o servidor.
Servidor recebe os dados.
Servidor trata os dados (se necessário)
Servidor encaminha os dados para B.

Sobre receber mensagens de um usuário específico, no momento de tratar via servidor você pode optar por re-enviar os dados para o usuário B ou não, ou seja, este controle fica a cargo do programador.

Você já tem algum código funcional para teste, talvez eu possa te ajudar a implementar o que você precisa/deseja fazer.

Comment: No momento não estou só vendo o funcionamento para converter um sistema de chat que tenho com verificações de x em x segundos em ajax para estes esquemas de sockets. Vou pesquisar mais e vou postando outras dúvidas obrigado.

Comment: Isso reduz bastante o consumo de banda e processamento do servidor quando ao formato que comentei acima né?

Comment: Sim,muito, principalmente por não ter que ficar abrindo milhares de conexões http só pra poder checar por nova mensagem